# OAuth2RestTemplate ""Access token denied."

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Trying to setup oauth2 authentication with 3rd party provider and it looks like for some reason it is not passing the client_id to the server.

```
 @Bean(name = "oauth2RestTemplate")
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate() {

    ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper()));
    messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory baseRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    baseRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    baseRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(60000);

    BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(baseRequestFactory);

    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
    interceptors.add(loggingRequestInterceptor());

    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(clientCredentialsResourceDetails(), oauth2Context());

    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2ClientContext oauth2Context()
{
    OAuth2ClientContext context = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    return context;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails clientCredentialsResourceDetails()
{
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(uri");
    resourceDetails.setClientId("client_id");
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret("clientsecret");
    return  resourceDetails;
}
```

Getting OAuth2AccessDeniedException
error="access_denied", error_description="Access token denied."

error="invalid_client", error_description="client_id was not supplied", code="62", correlationid="e0efacc2-4829-4dd7-8296-48c222992a84"

Comment: Issue was fixed after upgrading spring, http client versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgraded spring and http client versions and it worked